# Java Spring - Dynamic Schedule of function

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

I have been experimenting with Spring and i am new to it. I have worked with `Quartz` and i am well aware of it. But currently i am trying to do scheduling in `Spring`. I am trying to call a method every 5 second where my `cron` pattern comes from the `database`. Though i am able to set the `cron` pattern i am not sure how do i call the function. Please guide.

Code:

```
package com.test;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler;
import org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronTrigger;

public class Innovation implements Runnable
{
     public Innovation(TaskScheduler scheduler,String cron) 
     {
            scheduler.schedule(this, new CronTrigger("* * * ? * *"));
     }

     public void test()
     {
         System.out.println("This is new scheduled every 5 seconds");
     }

     @Bean
     public TaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
         //org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler
         return new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
     }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Innovation a=new Innovation(null, null);


    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing the [@Scheduled](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/) annotation on your test method. I'm also not sure you need as much code as what you have - here's a basic sample that shows how I'm using it:

```
@PropertySource(("classpath:event.properties"))
@Component
public class SerialNumbersToNetSuite {

    @Async
    @Scheduled(cron = "${sn_db_to_ns}") 
    public void start() throws SQLException, IOException, ServiceException, SOAPException {
        LOGGER.debug("Adding serial numbers...");
        ....
    }
    ....
}
```

event.properties has a line like:

```
sn_db_to_ns =  0 0 */2 * * *
```

and just in case you've missed the cron notation (or for any others who stumble upon this) [here is the cron format documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html)